# Convert a list of dictionary to a a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary which looks like:

```
list_dict = [{'test1':{'a':1,'b':12,'c':40,'d':120,'e':20,'f':1,'g':2,'h':'2'}},
                  {'test2':{'a':5,'b':'10','c':20}},
                   {'test3':{'e':21,'f':'18','g':22,'h':20}}]
```

I would want to convert this to a dataframe like this:
The keys should come as rows and tests should come as columns. and where the test doesn't have a key which is there in other tests should be filled with values as NAN

```
    mac_type  test1  test2  test3
    a         1      5      NAN
    b         12     10     NAN
    c         40     20     NAN
    d         120    NAN    NAN
    e         20     NAN    21
    f         1      NAN    18
    g         2      NAN    22
    h         2      NAN    20
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dict comprehension with flatten nested dicts and pass to `Dataframe` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: v for x in list_dict for k, v in x.items()})
print (df)
  test1 test2 test3
a     1     5   NaN
b    12    10   NaN
c    40    20   NaN
d   120   NaN   NaN
e    20   NaN    21
f     1   NaN    18
g     2   NaN    22
h     2   NaN    20
```

Or create `DataFrame` for each nested dictionary and pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), if large dictionaries and many of outer keys this should be slowier like first solution:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in list_dict], axis=1)
print (df)
  test1 test2 test3
a     1     5   NaN
b    12    10   NaN
c    40    20   NaN
d   120   NaN   NaN
e    20   NaN    21
f     1   NaN    18
g     2   NaN    22
h     2   NaN    20
```

Comment: @ansev - I think Mayank think answering, not performance ;)

Comment: Wow that was superfast. Thank you so much for your answer. I used the first approach which was faster as i had huge list of dictionary.

Comment: @ansev Yes, I meant jezrael answered real fast. I didn't talk about performance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` before build your `DataFrame`

```
from functools import reduce
df = pd.DataFrame(reduce(lambda cum_dict, new_dict: dict(cum_dict, **new_dict), 
                         list_dict))

print (df)
  test1 test2 test3
a     1     5   NaN
b    12    10   NaN
c    40    20   NaN
d   120   NaN   NaN
e    20   NaN    21
f     1   NaN    18
g     2   NaN    22
h     2   NaN    20
```